# How to get first line from file in Scala

Tags: parsing, scala, csv

I'd like to get just the first line from a CSV file in Scala, how would I go about doing that without using getLine(0) (it's deprecated)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

FWIW, here's what I would do (sticking w/ the standard library):

```
def firstLine(f: java.io.File): Option[String] = {
  val src = io.Source.fromFile(f)
  try {
    src.getLines.find(_ => true)
  } finally {
    src.close()
  }
}
```

Things to note:

1. The function returns `Option[String]` instead of `List[String]`, since it always returns one or none. That's more idiomatic Scala.
2. The `src` is properly closed, even in the very off chance that you could open the file, but reading throws an exception
3. Using `.find(_ => true)` to get the first item of the `Iterator` doesn't make me feel great, but there's no `nextOption` method, and this is better than converting to an intermediate `List` you don't use.
4. `IOException`s opening or reading the file are passed along.

I also recommend using the [scala-arm](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm) library to give you a better API for managing resources and automagically closing files when you need to.

```
import resource._

def firstLine(f: java.io.File): Option[String] = {
  managed(io.Source.fromFile(f)) acquireAndGet { src =>
    src.getLines.find(_ => true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

If you don't care about releasing the file resource after using it, the following is a very convienient way:

`Source.fromFile("myfile.csv").getLines.next()`

Comment: From one dave to another, this method fails to close the file descriptor. Do this too often, and you'll eventually have too many files open.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to close the file, and you want to get an empty collection rather than throw an error if the file is actually empty, then

```
val myLine = {
  val src = Source.fromFile("myfile.csv")
  val line = src.getLines.take(1).toList
  src.close
  line
}
```

is about the shortest way you can do it if you restrict yourself to the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I think all other solutions either read in all lines and then only retain the first line, or don't close the file. A solution which doesn't have these problems is:

```
val firstLine = {
  val inputFile = Source.fromFile(inputPath)
  val line = inputFile.bufferedReader.readLine
  inputFile.close
  line
}
```

I only have 1 week of experience with Scala so correct me if I'm wrong.