# count number of lines in file - Scala

Tags: parsing, scala, text

How would I go about counting the number of lines in a text file similar to `wc -l` on the unix command line in scala?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
io.Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.size
```

Note that `getLines` returns an `Iterator[String]` so you aren't actually reading the whole file into memory.

Comment: Similar to an answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8865434/115478), this also leaks file descriptors.

Answer (score 4):

Cribbing from [another answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8875087/115478):

```
def lineCount(f: java.io.File): Int = {
  val src = io.Source.fromFile(f)
  try {
    src.getLines.size
  } finally {
    src.close()
  }
}
```

Or, using [scala-arm](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm):

```
import resource._

def firstLine(f: java.io.File): Int = {
  managed(io.Source.fromFile(f)) acquireAndGet { src =>
    src.getLines.size
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val source = Source.fromFile(new File("file")).getLines
var n = 1 ; while (source.hasNext) { printf("%d> %s", n, source.next) ; n += 1 }


val source = Source.fromFile(new File("file")).getLines
for ((line, n) <- source zipWithIndex) { printf("%d> %s", (n + 1), line) }
```